# ASP.NET Core IdentityServer4 role is uppercase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, roles, identityserver4

I use the following sample as basis: [GitHub QuickStart](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src)

I added to *Config.cs* `UserClaims = new[] {ClaimTypes.Role}` to get the role of the authenticated user. Everything works fine and I can see the role if I'm writing the claims out, like: `role ADMIN`.

What im struggeling with is, that the role name is uppercase. In the database is the following entry:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59008a10cdaaf196d44bae8e"),
    "Name" : "Admin",
    "NormalizedName" : "ADMIN"
}
```

So is there a way to get the "real" name of the role?

Comment: This is a mongodb entry, which has nothing to do with the quickstart guide. So the reason you are reading out the normalized name is purely because of your implementation of adding custom roles. Post the relevant code.. e.g. your implementation of IProfileService.

Comment: @Mardoxx I am using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB`NuGet package to use MognoDb.